# Error when trying to use p-Dropdown from PrimeNG in application

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-dropdowns

I want to use [this PrimeNG-Dropdown](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/dropdown) in my application. So what I did:

```
npm i primeng --save
```

Then I added the `DropdownModule` in my imports from `app.module.ts`. Afterwards, I included the following code in my html:

```
<p-dropdown [options]="optionList" [(ngModel)]="selectionString" placeholder="Choose one"></p-dropdown>
```

On running `ng serve` and starting `localhost:4200` I get the following error:

> ./node_modules/primeng/components/multiselect/multiselect.js Module
>   not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/cdk/scrolling' in
>   '%projectroot%\node_modules\primeng\components\multiselect'

I also tried removing the import from the `imports`-Array, which resulted in a different error. What am I doing wrong? I am using Angular 7 btw.

When removing the import I get the following error:

```
Can't bind to 'options' since it isn't a known property of 'p-dropdown'.
1. If 'p-dropdown' is an Angular component and it has 'options' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'p-dropdown' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("
      <p-dropdown [ERROR ->][options]="optionList" [(ngModel)]="selectionString" placeholder="Choose one"></p-dropdown"): ng:///AppModule/ProjectGeneratorComponent.html@13:18
'p-dropdown' is not a known element:
1. If 'p-dropdown' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'p-dropdown' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("
      [ERROR ->]<p-dropdown [options]="optionList" [(ngModel)]="selectionString" placeholder="Choose one">"):
```

Comment: Could you please also paste the second error you are seeing after removing the module from imports?

Comment: @mpasko256 I updated my post

Answer (score 8, accepted):

if you want to use prime NG component, first you should do some steps and be careful about them that it has been done well. first you should install the packages through terminal in your code editor. you should install these:

```
    npm install primeng --save   //install prime in your machine

    npm install primeicons --save    //install prime icon in your machine
```

next : you should go to angular.json file in your project and in the style section you should copy these lines. these lines actually are the path of the libraries in your node_module folder. but something that is really important in this chapter is, which version of angular you are using. if you are using angular version 4 and less than that you should copy these path to the style chapter:

```
"../node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",
"../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/nova-light/theme.css",
"../node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
```

but if you are using version more than 4 it means 5 or 6 or 7 you should copy these path:

```
  "./node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",
  "./node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/nova-light/theme.css",
  "./node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
```

then you can go and simply import the primes module in your app.module and use the html markup to render the components. but be aware that some components need animations that you should install that on you machine through npm.

```
     npm install @angular/animations --save
```

and import modules in the app module:

```
 import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
```

i hope it helps you .

Answer (score 21):

You need to install Angular CDK.
use **npm install @angular/cdk --save** command.

and then import multi selecte module in appModule using

```
import {MultiSelectModule} from 'primeng/multiselect';
```

Comment: this is worked and thank you but I didnt't understand how this is solved. Can you explain?

Answer (score 0):

Try in appmodule.ts:

`import {CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA} from "@angular/core";`

```
@NgModule({
  ...
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Import FormsModule to the module where you imported the DropdownModule. I got the same issue, and that is how I resolved it.